# Mock Pipe in Angular Unit Test breaks ng-xi18n command

Tags: angular, jasmine, ngx-translate

I have a mock pipe replacing ngx-translate pipe for unit test:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'translate' })
export class MockTranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string): string {
        //Do stuff here, if you want
        return value;
    }
}
```

It's in file 'translate.service.mock.ts'. My tsconfig.app.json has excluded this file:

```
"exclude": [
        "test.ts",
        "**/*.mock.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts",
       "test/*.ts"
    ]
```

However, when I run ng-xi18n --i18nFormat=xlf2 --outFile=./assets/i18n/messages.xlf, it still complains:

> Cannot determine the module for class MockTranslatePipe in
>   src/test/translate.service.mock.ts! Add MockTranslatePipe to the
>   NgModule to fix it.

How to solve this problem? Thanks. (edited)

Comment: have you added `class MockTranslatePipe` inside `NgModule`. if not then add to `NgModule` file ? post your `*.module.ts` file if possible??

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the problem is with export that Pipe. As long as it's not exported, the ng-xi18n doesn't complain. But it means this mock pipe can't be shared across files.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'translate' })
class MockTranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string): string {
        //Do stuff here, if you want
        return value;
    }
}
```